# I am unable to install visual studio on chromebook

Tags: visual-studio, chromebook

I tried installing visual basic using Linux beta but I got an error message which says!

the following packages have unmet dependencies:

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you have to install the dependencies using your package manager.

`sudo apt install -y <depencies>` (In Ubuntu)

In [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/3t3lxw/what_package_management_system_does_chromeos_use/), I saw you can install packages using [Portage](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/packages/portage). But I think the standard is to use [ChromeBrew](https://github.com/skycocker/chromebrew).

You can dowloand the `vscode` for Gentoo/Portage [here](https://gpo.zugaina.org/app-editors/visual-studio-code).

Aloso, here you have a related question that might help you as well (for Ubuntu)=)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/563178/the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies